# Multiple Infinite While Loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

When given this snippet of code:

```
while(true){
 ...
}
```

How many times can this be asynchronously performed?

I've written this to test and how it interacts with [Google's JavaScript V8 Engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/) and only one while loop is active at a time.

```
var cycles = 0;
var counter = new Date();
var OpsStore = [];
var threads = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setTimeout(newThread(i),0);
}
function renew(){
    if (secondPassed(counter, new Date())){
        counter = new Date();
        Ops();
    }
    cycles++;
}

function newThread(id){
    threads.push({id: id, active: true});
    return function(){
        while(true){
            console.log(id);
            threads[id].active = true;
            renew();
        }
    }
}

function Ops(){
    OpsStore.push(cycles);
    console.log(cycles, ' avg: ', getAvgOps());
    console.log(threads);
    cycles = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
        threads[i].active = false;
    }
}

function secondPassed(d1, d2){
    return ((d2 - d1) >= 1000);  
}

function getAvgOps(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < OpsStore.length; i++){
        sum += OpsStore[i];
    }
    return sum / OpsStore.length;
}
```

Result:

```
4147371 ' avg: ' 4147371
[ { id: 0, active: true },
  { id: 1, active: true },
  { id: 2, active: true },
  { id: 3, active: true },
  { id: 4, active: true },
  { id: 5, active: true },
  { id: 6, active: true },
  { id: 7, active: true },
  { id: 8, active: true },
  { id: 9, active: true } ]
4071504 ' avg: ' 4109437.5
[ { id: 0, active: true },
  { id: 1, active: false },
  { id: 2, active: false },
  { id: 3, active: false },
  { id: 4, active: false },
  { id: 5, active: false },
  { id: 6, active: false },
  { id: 7, active: false },
  { id: 8, active: false },
  { id: 9, active: false } ]
```

For educational purposes, is it possible to have more than ONE while loop constantly iterating in JavaScript?

Comment: In what sense to you want to have multiple while loops running? Do you mean pre-emptively?

Comment: @RayToal I do not follow, could you elaborate? This serves an experimental/education purpose.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "performed asynchronously"... Javascript is run synchronously.  When things run in an async fashion in javascript they are actually just waiting for some even to trigger and start running whatever callback code is associated with the event.  When you run javascript it is single threaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are missing something fundamental to how javascript works.  Javascript is single threaded.  For more details please see this reference in the MDN docs:
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Once an event is triggered the event callback will execute until completion.  Any events which occur during this time will be pushed to the event queue.  Once the current execution is complete it will begin the next from the event queue.

The reason this behavior is because the first would continue execution until completion and only then will the second event begin execution.

Comment: Completely forgot about the event loops. Thanks!

Comment: Node.js has the ability to do the multiprocess thing, but it's more like Web Workers than anything else.

Comment: @speedyninja Node.js is no more capable of doing "multiprocess" things than any other javascript engine.  The method used to accomplish such tasks are calling some binding API which runs outside of the javascript engine.  When the task completes it triggers an event which is pushed to an event queue just like any other event in javascript.  One inherent problem with Node.js is if you don't run multiple instances you can't take advantage of multiple cores because of this fact.

Comment: @Goblinlord The [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) Module allows you to spin up versions of the same file in different processes, but again, they act like Web Workers, and you have to do special function calls to communicate between them. **I agree with you. JavaScript, by design, is single threaded.** However, this doesn't mean that you can only ever run 1 process per script. That is all I'm pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Accepting that this is just an experiment, you could look into [generators/iterators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:generators) to allow one "loop" to yield, allowing the next to run.  However, as goblinlord already stated in his answer true concurrency is beyond a single JS engine.

David Walsh has written a [good tutorial on generators](https://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators).

Note that these are defined in ES6, and are [not implemented natively in all browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) right now, but there are polyfills/shims for them.  Here is a [random blog post](http://gu.illau.me/posts/polyfilling-generators/) I found talking about that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NO, you can not run several while loops simultaneously. As others have said, Javascript is single threaded and will only execute the events on the event loop when nothing is running on the main thread. Because your while loop never ends, it never returns the control to the javascript engine.

However, you can use recursion to alternate the execution of several functions infinitely (or until event queue gets starved)

You can do somehting like this

```
var threads = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  setTimeout(newThread(i),0);
}
function newThread(id){
    threads.push({id: id, active: true});
    console.log(id);
    threads[id].active = true;
    return function(){
        setTimeout(newThread(id),0)
    }
}
```